# Sanitizer life expectancy

Tags: sanitizer, starsan

I’ve got sanitizer I made before Christmas, brewing tomorrow. Wondering if it’s still effective-is there a shelf life on clean sanitizer water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what kind of sanatiser it is, many will keep thier sanitising properties indefinitely and through many uses.

Acid based sanitisers like StarSan are effective as long as thier pH is below 3.0. A simple pH test is used to check it.

Other sanitisers like iodine based sanitisers are intended as a single use and disposed of after 24 hours.

Comment: Awesome, that’s great to know thank you! I’ll start checking the pH level before each session or usage

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with making a new batch sanitizing solution. I used to have solution on a spray bottle, and my experience was that performance degraded after a few weeks.